# how to enforce constraint in sql?

Tags: sql

I have a question regarding enforce a constraint to my table.
I have a table called workson and a table called staff, each staff has specific title(supervisor,authorizer,manager,...). I need to ensure that the supervisor and the authorizer cannot be the same staff on workson table.The cardinality between them is many to many. I am not sure how to do it.
Can you please advise me to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS? SQL Server/Oracle etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following query

```
SELECT AssignmentNo, StaffNo
  FROM worksOnStaff
 WHERE StaffType = 'supervisor'
INTERSECT 
SELECT AssignmentNo, StaffNo
  FROM worksOnStaff
 WHERE StaffType = 'authorizer'
```

When the data in the table satisifes your constraint the above query will be the empty set i.e.

```
CHECK ( NOT EXISTS ( SELECT AssignmentNo, StaffNo
                       FROM worksOnStaff
                      WHERE StaffType = 'supervisor'
                     INTERSECT 
                     SELECT AssignmentNo, StaffNo
                       FROM worksOnStaff
                      WHERE StaffType = 'authorizer' ) );
```

The problem is, few SQL products allow a subquery in a `CHECK` constraint.

The usual workaround is to implment the same logic in procedural code e.g. using a trigger or forcing users to update data via a stored procedures (by removing update privileges on the base tables) that ensure the constraint is never violated. You have to take care to serialize updates properly without making the whole thing run like glue.

Happily, there is an excellent book on the subject:

[Applied Mathematics for Database Professionals By Lex de Haan, Toon Koppelaars](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-uYZcnEt4uQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=applied+mathematics+for+database+professionals&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yliaT_yBBsim0QWCyqmXDw&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=serialization%20strategy&f=false)

> For implementing constraints that cannot be declared to the DBMS, we prefer to follow the triggered procedural strategy... Like declared constraints, the triggered procedural strategy cannot be subverted; ...is likely to create a more manageable code architecture ...[however] implementing efficient data integrity code for these constraints through triggers is far from being a trivial task... 
>   However, you’ll experience that by implementing table constraints regularly and becoming
>   proficient in doing so, implementing table constraints procedurally is in general quite
>   doable...
>
> execution model EM6: On-Transition-Effect-Property Plus Optimized-Query
>
> 1. Translate the formal specification into a constraint validation query.
> 2. Develop code to maintain transition effects.
> 3. Devise transition effect (TE) queries that ensure the constraint validation query is only run when
>      necessary.
> 4. Discover a means to optimize the constraint validation query by having the TE query
>      provide values that can be used in the validation query.
> 5. Devise and add a serialization strategy to the data integrity (DI) code.

They give full details on how to implement such a strategy in Oracle which can be ported to other SQL products.

Answer (score 0):

Some databases support a check constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE workson
(
    rowId int NOT NULL,
    supervisorId int NOT NULL,
    authorizerId int NOT NULL,
    -- ...
    CONSTRAINT chk_Uniqueness CHECK (supervisorId != authorizerId)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond, but there is only staffId attribute in the table. The staff title will define the staff roles.

Comment: @user1360341 - Then I don't understand what you really want. Could you please post the table structures.

Comment: Here is my table schema http://sqlhelp1.blogspot.com.au/. I need to ensure that the supervisor and the authorizer cannot be the same staff for any given work.

Comment: @user1360341 - But then you just need a unique constraint on `AssignmentNo` and `StaffNo`. Btw. it would have been helpful for others reading this question if you would have posted the schema into your question.

Comment: So you mean if I use unique constraint for those two attributes it will solve the problem?

Comment: @user1360341 - I'm not sure if it will solve your problem, but it'll ensure that no `StaffNo` is *assigned* more than once to a certain `AssignmentNo`. In other words no person can work more than once on a single task.

Comment: What if, other roles are able to be assigned to more than one particular assignment?
For example Mary green can be a supervisor and a sales person of the particular assignment but she cannot be the authorizer for particular assignment?

Comment: @mrab: "Some databases support a check constraint" -- `CHECK` constraint enforcement is a feature of the DBMS, not the database.